# Loss function doesn't converge after vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gradient, loss

For a reinforcement learning project that I'm working on, which is based on Deep Q-learning from Demonstrations (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03732.pdf) the training process took a long time, because of a for loop in my loss function (this function is called in my loss function):

```
def QmaxExp(state,model,Expert_action,OutsideConditions,setpoint,Inputdf):
   maxValue = -1000000
   for i in range(len(Inputdf)):
      Actions = np.array([Inputdf['col1'][i],Inputdf['col2'][i],Inputdf['col3'][i],Inputdf['col4'][i]])
       conditions = np.array(list(OutsideConditions.values()))
       Inputs = np.concatenate((state,conditions,[setpoint]))
       Qvalue = model(Inputs.reshape((1,18)))[0,i]
       Value = Qvalue + Lfunction(Actions,Expert_action) * 0.01
       if Value > maxValue:
           maxValue = Value
   return maxValue
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
def QmaxExp(state, model, Expert_action, OutsideConditions, setpoint, Inputdf):
   conditions = np.array(list(OutsideConditions.values()))
   Inputs = np.concatenate((state, conditions, [setpoint]))
   Qvalues = model(Inputs.reshape((1, 18)))[0]
   Actions = np.array(Inputdf[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']])
   Lfunctie_value = (np.subtract(Actions,Expert_action)**2).sum(axis=1) #use np.sum(...) when using old function
   Values = Qvalues + Lfunctie_value * 0.01
   return np.max(Values)
```

This code is way faster (40 times) and the return maxValue (and loss value) is also the same, but in my training process the first QmaxExp converged to a loss of ~20, while the second is not converging at all and is around ~330.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    rest of the code...
    loss += custom_loss(model,modelTarget,Current_state,Next_state,actions,Expert_action,Reward,gamma,OutsideConditions,Setpoint,Inputdf,HeatingInput,OtherInput)
    lossNew += custom_lossNew(model,modelTarget,Current_state,Next_state,actions,Expert_action,Reward,gamma,OutsideConditions,Setpoint,Inputdf,HeatingInput,OtherInput)
        # loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(loss)
    loss = loss/Batch_size
    lossNew = lossNew/Batch_size
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

The custom loss is defined as:

```
def custom_loss(model,modelTarget,state,new_state,action,Expert_action,reward,gamma,OutsideConditions,setpoint,Inputdf,HeatingInput,OtherInput):
   JDQ = (reward + gamma*  QmaxT1(modelTarget,new_state,OutsideConditions,setpoint) - Qvalue(state,action,model,OutsideConditions,setpoint,HeatingInput,OtherInput,Inputdf))**2
   JE = QmaxExp(state,model,Expert_action,OutsideConditions,setpoint,Inputdf) - QExp(state,model,Expert_action,OutsideConditions,setpoint,HeatingInput,OtherInput,Inputdf)
   JL2 = (reward - Qvalue(state,action,model,OutsideConditions,setpoint,HeatingInput,OtherInput,Inputdf))**2

   lambda1 = 1
   lambda2 = 1
   lambda3 = 1

   Loss = lambda1 * JDQ + lambda2 * JE + lambda3 * JL2
   return Loss
```

And the L function is a simple sum of my array:

```
def Lfunction(action,Expert_action):
   return np.sum(np.subtract(action,Expert_action)**2)#.sum(axis=1) #use np.sum(...) when using old function
```

Does anyone know what could go wrong in the vectorized QmaxExp?

The model architecture is an input layer, then 25 nodes and the output is 625 nodes. Not worked on a proper network yet, since speed was the main problem first

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show more code. Where in the training process is `QmaxExp`? What does `custom_loss` do? What does `Lfunction()` do?

Comment: i've updated the code :) if it's not clear, i will add more :)

Comment: I'm surprised you get gradients with numpy functions inside your gradient tape. Normally, gradient information is lost if you use non-TensorFlow functions (like np.sum()) to compute the loss. What shape has `Values`? Is `model(Inputs.reshape((1,18)))` the same input for every loop iteration?

Comment: I converted the numpy functions to TF functions and it looks like it's getting a much better, thank you very much @mhenning :D